# Change available attributes on common element based on location in an xsd

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm using a complex common type in an xsd, and I'd like to change the possible values for one of the attributes depending on the location (xpath) of the element.

I am currently using an enumerated set to define the possible values, but I would like to have 3 possible values for this attribute if the element appears in one particular location in the xml document, and 2 possible values if it appears anywhere else.

Is it possible to enforce this constraint with an xsd? I know I could just define 2 seperate elements, but the element in question contains many child elements and attributes, and I only need to make a change to one particular attribute.

The validation engine we are using is only Schema 1.0 complient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want is to avoid writing out the many child elements and attributes twice, use named groups (and see [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24038492/child-type-redefines-only-one-element-from-parent-type)).

If it's important to you that the elements in question be explicitly related in the type system, things get more complicated, but the technique is well worth learning.

One approach is to use type restriction, and the limited amount of context-awareness that local element declarations give you, to bind the attribute to different types in the different contexts in question.  To do this:

1. Define a type for the attribute which accepts the union of all the value-sets. (This will have five possible values if the three-valued and two-valued versions of the attribute accept disjoint sets of values; it will have only three if the two-valued set simply removes one possibility from the set.)  I'll call this TA1.
2. Define two further types for the attribute, specifying the sets of three and two values you want for particular locations and deriving them from TA1 by restriction.  I'll call these TA2 and TA3.
3. Now define a base form of the complex type, in which the attribute in question has type TA1.  Define two other forms of the complex type, for use in the two different (sets of) contexts in which you want to restrict the attribute's values.  I'll call these CT1, CT2, CT3.
4. Based on the context, bind the appropriate element either to CT2 or to CT3, to get the desired behavior.  Depending on how the contexts are to be distinguished, you may need distinct types for other elements as well.  There is a detailed description of how this works in [a paper I wrote long ago for the XML Schema working group at W3C](http://www.w3.org/2000/04/26-csrules.html).

You don't describe your specific case in enough detail to allow a sample solution.  But imagine that inside the `frontmatter` and `backmatter` elements, we wanted the `para` element to accept the values 'hot' and 'mild' in its `chili` attribute, but inside the `body` element the only acceptable values are `red`, `green`, and `christmas`.

First, we define the three types mentioned above.

```
<xs:simpleType name="TA1">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:enumeration value="hot"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="mild"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="red"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="green"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="christmas"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:simpleType name="TA2">
  <xs:restriction base="tns:TA1">
    <xs:enumeration value="hot"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="mild"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:simpleType name="TA3">
  <xs:restriction base="tns:TA1">
    <xs:enumeration value="red"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="green"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="christmas"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

The derivation relation among these is important, because it's what makes it legal to substitute TA2 and TA3 for TA1 when defining restrictions of the enclosing complex type:

```
<xs:complexType name="CT1" mixed="true">
  <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <xs:element ref="tns:emph"/>
    <xs:element ref="tns:q"/>
  </xs:choice>
  <xs:attribute name="chile" type="tns:TA1"/>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="CT2">
  <xs:complexContent mixed="true">
    <xs:restriction base="tns:CT1">
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element ref="tns:emph"/>
        <xs:element ref="tns:q"/>
      </xs:choice>
      <xs:attribute name="chile" type="tns:TA2"/>        
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="CT3">
  <xs:complexContent mixed="true">
    <xs:restriction base="tns:CT1">
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element ref="tns:emph"/>
        <xs:element ref="tns:q"/>
      </xs:choice>
      <xs:attribute name="chile" type="tns:TA3"/>        
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

This allows us to define two versions of the `para` element, depending on context: one with the `chili` attribute typed using tns:TA2 and one typed using tns:TA3.  The complication in this case is that paragraphs can (we assume) appear as children of a variety of different elements, which must also be typed in two different ways to reflect which context they are in.  Our declarations for document, frontmatter, body, backmatter, and div look like this:

```
<xs:element name="document" type="tns:document"/>

<xs:complexType name="document">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="frontmatter" type="tns:front-back-section"/>
    <xs:element name="body" type="tns:section"/>
    <xs:element name="backmatter" type="tns:front-back-section"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="front-back-section">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="para" type="tns:CT2" 
                minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    <xs:element name="div" type="tns:front-back-section" 
                minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="section">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="para" type="tns:CT3" 
                minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    <xs:element name="div" type="tns:section" 
                minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

In a simpler version of this vocabulary we would have one type for div and one type for para; what is going on here is essentially that in this more complex version we have split each of those types into two and bound the div and para elements now to one and now to the other.  By binding div either to tns:section or to tns:front-back section, we make the div element carry one bit of information from its parent to its children, namely "are we inside the main body, or inside the front or back matter?"  This information allows the para element, in turn, to be bound correctly either to tns:CT2 or to tns:CT3. The same technique can be used in writing context-free grammars, to carry finite bits of information about the context around.  (One bit of information requires doubling all the states that need to carry that bit.)  And of course the technique can also be used in Relax NG schemas.  It cannot be used in DTDs, because they do not allow a given element type name to be bound to more than one type (or equivalently, they do not allow a given element type name to be used in more than one element declaration).

Answer (score 0):

You can use **XSD 1.1** where you will have some options. One would be [type alternatives](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#cTypeAlternative) for elements, but since the test is based on *context* and that would require XPath tests on the parent axis, it wouldn't work since XSD actually supports a XPath subset which doesn't allow such matches.

But you can use an `<xs:assert>` in an type higher up in the hierarchy and use XPath to restrict atrributes and values in the child nodes.

Assume you have an element like this one:

```
<xs:element name="anElement">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:attribute name="a1">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:enumeration value="one"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="two"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="three"/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:attribute>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

And that element may occur in a `root` or a `child` element:

```
<xs:element name="child">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="anElement"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="anElement"/>
            <xs:element ref="child" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

And that you want to establish a rule such as: "if `<anElement>` is a child of `<root>` then the `@a` attribute may have the values `one` or `two`. If it is child of `<child>` then the values can be only `two` or `three`.

You can enforce that rule by adding an `<xs:assert>` in the context of the `<root>` element declaration:

```
<xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>...</xs:sequence>
        <xs:assert test="(anElement/@a1='one' or anElement/@a1='two') and 
                         (child/anElement/@a1='two' or child/anElement/@a1='three')"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Then a situation like this would be *valid*:

```
<root>
    <anElement a1="one"/>
    <child>
        <anElement a1="three"/>
    </child>
</root>
```

But this would *fail* validation in both instances of `<anElement>`:

```
<root>
    <anElement a1="three"/> <!-- only 'one' or 'two' are allowed -->
    <child>
        <anElement a1="one"/> <!-- only 'two' or 'three' are allowed -->
    </child>
</root>
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but the validation engine we are using (Sterling Integrator) is only schema 1.0 compliant. I will edit/update the question.

Comment: In that case you can also try using an extension, such as [Schematron](http://www.schematron.com/) which will allow you to apply rules in XPath using `<xs:appInfo>` elements, or even use Schematron by itself.